# Modulus of numbers for negative divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

How does the Google calculator or the Wolfram calculator calculate the modulus of the numbers with negative divisors?

For example: -4 % -3 = -1 and 4 % -3 = -2

The same topic has been mentioned here too : http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html#buksxvr under the heading **Remainder after division for Negative divisor**.

Please explain the procedure in which the answer for such negative divisors can be reached at.

Thank you!

Comment: $(x \% a )-a= x \% (-a)$

Comment: $a=b\mod m$ iff $a=b\bmod -m$.

Comment: @almagest So then '3 mod 2' and '3 mod -2' may both have the same answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The operator $\mod{}$** : You have the equality $x=a\pmod p \iff x=a\pmod {-p}$, indeed : $$x=a\pmod p \iff x = a +kp \iff x = a + (-k)(-p)=a\pmod {-p}$$

**The software operator $\%$** : If you compute $x \% p$ with $p \geq 0$, it will return the smallest positive $a$ such as $x=a \pmod p$, but if you compute $x \% p$ with $p \le 0$ , it will return the biggest negative $a$ such as $x=a \pmod p$.
Finally : $$\forall p \geq 0,x \% (-p)=(x \% p )-p$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had read this statement not so long ago that : 'Sign of result of mod operation on negative numbers is sign of the dividend.' Your answer cleared the doubt.